# Showing that Paley Graphs are Edge-Transitive

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I would like to show that Paley graph are rank $3$ graphs (i.e. Vertex-Transitive, Edge-Transitive and Non-Edge-Transitive).

Showing that they are vertex transitive is easy - every $x \mapsto x+k$ is an automorphism in $GF(q)$ and so, for example, the automorphism $x \mapsto x+1$ shows that they are vertex transitive.

I also know how to show that they are self-complimentary and thus if I can show one of edge-transitivity/non-edge transitivity I get the other.

Can anyone help with how to show that they are indeed edge-transitive (or non-edge-transitive).

Thanks!

Comment: Use multiplication in $GF(q)$.  I'm voting to close because this isn't a research-level question.

Comment: Agree with @Andreas, and especially since the question is poorly worded.